# Redirect subdomain to https with htaccess

Tags: .htaccess, redirect, mod-rewrite, https, subdomain

I want to redirect all URLs only from one subdomain to https.

My URL http://nip.domain.com/sitexy.html should be https://nip.domain.com/sitexy.html

With this code I will be redirected to the home page with https and the path will be removed:

```
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} off
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(nip)\. [NC]
RewriteRule (.*) https://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [R]
```

Can anybody give me a hint, how to keep the path behind the domain?
Thanks!

Comment: the path should not ideally be removed, since you're using `%{REQUEST_URI}`